# When should I consider splitting up my Eclipse projects into different workpaces?

Tags: eclipse

I have some trouble understanding the concept of workspaces in Eclipse, and how I should treat it differently from e.g. working sets or folders. Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workspace is a folder where your projects reside. Additionally it contains meta-data like saved perspectives, text editor preferences, etc. (all the stuff you find in Window -> Preferences). You can work with exactly one workspace per Eclipse instance at a time.

A working set is just a collection of projects within a workspace. For example, you can use working sets to group projects according to some criterion. This is useful when you have many projects.

So, essentially the workspace is the place where your projects reside physically and where your preferences are stored, and working sets are just logical project sets, i.e. views of the contents in the workspace.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. From my understanding, if I keep all my different projects in the same place physically I shouldn't have a reason to create another workspace? The internal organization of e.g. school and work should thereafter be done though the use of working sets?

Comment: This is a matter of personal preference. I use one workspace and organize the projects in working sets. This means also that I only need to configure my workspace (set the preferences) once, which is not the case when you have multiple workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful for different workspace preference (like default encoding UTF-8 or not, etc...)
Personnaly I use 3 workspaces :
1 for my job
2 for my personal use : I have 2 because they are in different places on my hard disk according to my "backup" strategy (one I use SVN, the other one I use google drive I don't want pollute my google drive with too many projects so I split)

Comment: +1 for mentioning backups; this is often overlooked. It's not necessary to backup the workspace metadata, just the project source.

Answer (score 0):

**WORKSPACES:**

I would create another workspace other than the default one as follows for an example:

-one for school's projects

-one for projects which you use to help other people with their code here

**PROJECTS:**

You create a project which defines in general what the program is about, for example: 'converter' which converts money to $, €, etc.

A project helps you organise and store all related packages and folders which store icons, text files, etc to be used/manipulated from your program.

**What about packages ?**

A package  helps you organize your classes into a folder structure and make it easy to locate and use them.

Mostly important it helps you improve re-usability.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is optimized at handling lots of small-medium sized projects.

Optionally, you can close projects and then hide closed projects.  This will give you a boost in performance.

You can also create working sets of projects so you can flip back and forward between views of related projects without incurring the overhead of restarting eclipse with a new workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I would split projects out into different workspaces when:

- I don't want clients to see my other projects when working on-site (workspace-per-client)
- When I want to use different versions of dependent projects as part of the source build
- when I want to play, I have a separate 'playground' workspace for completely throwaway work, and a 'samples' workspace for code that is standalone but should be kept.

A per-project or -application strategy is also good if that fits your workflow. I don't keep source code within the workspace folder (it's checked out from source control), so it's purely metadata and run/debug configurations.